# Simple user registration without captcha or e-mail verifiaction with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms, .net-3.5, registration

I want to create a simple user registration form with First / Last name, email, and password. We have used captcha and email verification in the past to ward off bots, but is there another way without using those techniques?  I thought about encrypting the field ID names so that they aren’t names username, password, etc. we tried openID, but 1% of our users had an ID they could use. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [Akisment](http://akismet.com/) (you don't have to have WordPress to use it) in order to determine if it's spam. Though I think Akismet is best suited to situations when there is text to validate, it might be able to help validate emails and names.

At the very least, if you want to remove a CAPTCHA, you should have some sort of throttling to ensure that a single IP address can't register more than x number of times during y period of time.